# How to track peak memory consumed by android application

Tags: android, memory, ddms

Is there anyway to find the peak memory consumed by the application while running.Normally an application will take some memory and While the application is running it will consume somemore memory and again will release after the operations were done.I want to note that peak memory consumed by my apllication while running(Graphical representation).

In DDMS the heap Tab shows the heap size totally used by the application.But I want how much the app consumed and then released the memory each time while running.Is there any tool or eclipse plugin to track this?Kindly suggest a solution.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html - you should take a look at this and use the hprof tools to discover your memory issues.